# Linking error when trying to compile haskell code

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

```
Linking 1 ...
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lgmp
/home/sam/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/integer-gmp-1.0.3.0/libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.3.0.a(Type.o):ghc_4.c:function integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_zdwplusBigNatWord_info: error: undefined reference to '__gmpn_add_1'
/home/sam/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/integer-gmp-1.0.3.0/libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.3.0.a(Type.o):ghc_4.c:function integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_zdwminusBigNatWord_info: error: undefined reference to '__gmpn_sub_1'
/home/sam/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/integer-gmp-1.0.3.0/libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.3.0.a(Type.o):ghc_4.c:function integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_zdwtimesBigNatWord_info: error: undefined reference to '__gmpn_mul_1'
/home/sam/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/integer-gmp-1.0.3.0/libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.3.0.a(Type.o):ghc_4.c:function integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_zdwgo_info: error: undefined reference to '__gmpn_add'
/home/sam/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/integer-gmp-1.0.3.0/libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.3.0.a(Type.o):ghc_4.c:function integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_zdwminusBigNat_info: error: undefined reference to '__gmpn_sub'
/home/sam/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/integer-gmp-1.0.3.0/libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.3.0.a(Type.o):ghc_4.c:function integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_zdwtimesBigNat_info: error: undefined reference to '__gmpn_mul'
/home/sam/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/integer-gmp-1.0.3.0/libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.3.0.a(Type.o):ghc_4.c:function integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_plusInteger_info: error: undefined reference to '__gmpn_cmp'
/home/sam/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/integer-gmp-1.0.3.0/libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.3.0.a(Type.o):ghc_4.c:function integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_leIntegerzh_info: error: undefined reference to '__gmpn_cmp'
/home/sam/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/integer-gmp-1.0.3.0/libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.3.0.a(Type.o):ghc_4.c:function integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_leIntegerzh_info: error: undefined reference to '__gmpn_cmp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

Comment: looks like you are compiling some gmp Haskell library, but that your system has no `gmp` library installed to link to. (`apt-get install libgmp-dev`).

Answer (score 7):

Installing `libgmp-dev` using `sudo apt install libgmp-dev` resolved the issue for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's worth noting that this is one of the packages ghcup lists as a dependency during installation.